# ListView making in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter

I have a Firebase database with few values of customers as shown below. (I mentioned the child in brackets)

```
-Sooraj (child(registered user))
     -January(child(month))
           -Aswathy(child(name))
               -address: ""
               -cost: ""
               -details: ""
               -email: ""
               -name: "Aswatyy" - (child ("name"))-
               -phone: "944346848494"
               -received: ""
               -status: "Proposal Sent"
```

I need to take the child ("name") from database and put it in a `ListView`.

My  `declaration` as

```
ListView customerList;
List<String> customerArray = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

then

```
customerList=findViewById(R.id.customerlistView);
```

ListView populating code as

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(month);
    DatabaseReference NameRef = ref.child("name");

    NameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                String nameDatabase = postSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                customerArray.add(nameDatabase);
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, customerArray);
                customerList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.w("name","load:onCancelled",databaseError.toException());

        }
    });
```

Nothing happening. Where I went wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of names then try the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(registeredUser);
 DatabaseReference nameRef = ref.child(month);

NameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            String name=postSnapshot.getKey();
            customerArray.add(name);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, customerArray);
            customerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        Log.w("name","load:onCancelled",databaseError.toException());

    }
});
```

Assuming you have this db:

```
Sooraj
   January
      Aswathy
         address:...
         name:...
```

`getKey()` will retrieve the names in the database

Comment: I will check and let you know

Answer (score 1):

```
  final ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<>();
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("User").child(userName).child(monthName);

        final ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    HashMap nameModel = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    String name =(String) nameModel.get("name");
                    names.add(name);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

from above method you can get the name array and you can set it to your adapter

Your table will be like this

```
User
   -registeredUserName
            -monthName
              -childName
                   name
```

if you do not have User as a table name

```
 -registeredUserName
            -monthName
              -childName
                   name
```

then just pass

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(userName).child(monthName);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to display all those names, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference monthRef = rootRef.child(registeredUser).child(month);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(name);
        }
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
monthRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which `registeredUser` as in your example is `Sooraj` and the `month` is `January`.

The output will be:

```
Aswatyy
//All the other names
```

In your code, there are two major issues. First one would be your reference, which in `ref` is missing a child and in the `NameRef` points to property which is useless. The second problem is that you are creating and setting the adapter inside the for loop which will end up having a single item displayed (the last item).

Comment: You were asking for `-name: "Aswatyy" - (child ("name"))-` right?